# Sort several 'linked' Lists

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

I have 3 lists so the order of their elements is important:

```
names: [a, b, c, d]
files: [a-file, b-file, c-file, d-file]
counts: [a-count, b-count, c-count, d-count]
```

I need to sort **all of them** alphabetically based on  the `List<String> names` elements.
Can someone explain me how to do this?

Comment: Use a data structure instead of "parallel lists".

Comment: Am I understanding you right that if `names` was `[d, c, b, a]`, you'd want `files` and `counts` to be reverse alphabetical order? I think a bit more detail might be useful, but most likely you're looking for the `Comparator<T>` interface, which you can provide to `List.sort()`

Comment: To elaborate on "millimoose" suggestion - use one list of data structures/classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a class to hold the tuple:

```
class NameFileCount {
    String name;
    File file;
    int count;

    public NameFileCount(String name, File file, int count) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then group the data from the three lists into a single list of this class:

```
List<NameFileCount> nfcs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
    NameFileCount nfc = new NameFileCount(
        names.get(i),
        files.get(i),
        counts.get(i)
    );
    nfcs.add(nfc);
}
```

And sort this list by `name`, using a custom comparator:

```
Collections.sort(nfcs, new Comparator<NameFileCount>() {
    public int compare(NameFileCount x, NameFileCount y) {
        return x.name.compareTo(y.name);
    }
});
```

(Property accessors, null checking, etc omitted for brevity.)

Comment: Or implement `Comparable<NameFileCount>` and make `Collections.sort()` more re-usable.